# Extending Devtools to dissect websocket frames

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I have written a few dissectors in Lua for Wireshark, [for example](https://github.com/martin-cowie/wireshark-dissector). I would like to know if Devtools can be extended to achieve similar effects. There are a few reasons this is desirable:

1. Installing and using Wireshark often mandates privileged access.
2. Capturing traffic from the loopback NIC on Windows remains problematic.
3. websocket traffic is included in saved `HAR` files, suitable for later dissection.
4. Devtools can inspect SSL secured websocket frames with zero user effort.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with Firefox.

There is an addon already that hooks into the WebSocket data. It can do some additional parsing of protocols on top of WebSockets like MQTT.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/websocket-monitor/

It appears to hook into nsIWebSocketEventService to get the data. I haven't found any documentation for it.
https://github.com/firebug/websocket-monitor/blob/master/lib/wsm-actor.js#L80

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not appear to allow access to WebSocket frame data through an API.
You may be able to modify the WebSocket constructor to allow you to intercept the events from your plugin.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/7_a0W8Y92O4